# SMB network shares and symbolic links

Tags: mount, network-shares, samba, symbolic-link

I'm experimenting with Samba shares at home and I'm trying to understand how symbolic links work.
I have a few network shares on a couple of machines that run a mix of Windows and Ubuntu or Debian distros.
I'm trying to understand a few things:

- is it possible to allow for the creation of symbolic links (from any client) inside the shares and across shares but not outside shared paths? For example if I have `/srv/share1` and `/srv/share2` would it be possible to link:

  ```
  /srv/share1/link -> /srv/share1/file
  ```

  and

  ```
  /srv/share2/link -> /srv/share1/file
  ```

  but not any file outside these 2 directories?
- is it possible to make symlinks "transparent" on any client or specific clients when mounting the shares? Are there specific options I should use when mounting them on other machines to see links as such?
  Right now mounting them using `cifs` shows symlinks as it was a normal files (I didn't set any options using the command beside authentication).
  This answer: [Deleting Ubuntu folder symlink deletes target folder's contents when done via OSX & Samba](https://superuser.com/questions/1140404/deleting-ubuntu-folder-symlink-deletes-target-folders-contents-when-done-via-os) seems to support this behaviour.
- I'd like to get a clearer understanding on which are the pros and cons of various options used to manage links; in particular which are the advantages and disadvantages of:

  ```
  [global]
  allow insecure wide links = Yes
  unix extensions = Yes
  wide links = Yes
  ```

  instead of:

  ```
  [global]
  unix extensions = No  # Does this imply UNIX clients cannot create symlinks?
  wide links = Yes
  ```

  besides the obvious security problem related to `allow insecure wide links` being turned on.
  The above config is from: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5120/181086

A partial answer is given here: [creating symbolic links on networked drive](https://superuser.com/q/1017653/312769) but it's related to Windows.
Other answers such as:
[Ubuntu + latest samba version, symlinks no longer work on share mounted in windows](https://superuser.com/q/128716/312769)
[Creating a Symlink in an NTFS share](https://superuser.com/q/681122/312769)
aren't really recent and don't go in-depth in the reasons why it does or doesn't work.
Finally this one I didn't understand [Samba Linux shares -- Why won't windows machines display/follow symbolic links?](https://superuser.com/q/466278/312769).

Comment: This question as asked is a bit too broad. The first thing you need to understand is that links are a Filesystem concept, and whilie Samba does present a set of virtualized filesystem semantics to clients, it sits atop the real filesystem implementation on the server. Ultimately, that means that the difference between creating links on the native filesystem, vs simply dereferencing links them for browsing and access are somewhat differant problems. I've never seen a mechanism for making symlinks over shares, but I've commony set up symlinks within shared directories for clients to access.